# How do I split a database column in to separate, query-able values?

Tags: sql-server

I have no idea how to do this query. I need to grab a bunch of information, but it's all in one column. If the table rotated 90 degreses to the right it'd be just fine... lol...

The ObjectInternalID column represents one event.
**Conditions**
I want all event(s) details(Values Column)
only for one person `where values = "his name"`
within a specific date range `where values > "date range"`

Any idea what the easiest way to do this is?

[image]

**PROGRESS UPDATE**

I'm trying to create a temp table out of this, but I get issues when I add the `into` statement.

```
select 
    s.ObjectInternalID
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 3 then Value end) as date1
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 4 then Value end) as resident1
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 66 then Value end) as attending1
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 14 then Value end) as date2
into 
    #TempQueryTable(
     MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 3 then Value end) as date1
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 4 then Value end) as resident1
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 66 then Value end) as attending1
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 14 then Value end) as date2
from 
    DocUserDefinedData s
group by 
    s.ObjectInternalID
```

If I comment out the into section, it runs, but otherwise I get an "incorrect syntac ',' error. I don't see

Comment: How would you correlate the values in one row to the values in another row? Based on the ObjectInternalID value?

Comment: So you want `values > "date range"` or ` > date` ?? Also what are those values obfuscates? Because if arent date would be very hard to compare

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense, but you should check for `PIVOT`

Comment: Your newest code has two major problems. First, when you use select into you don't list out the columns or whatever it is you are doing there. Second, since this is coming from an EAV style table you need to convert this data into usable datatypes. You do not want everything as varchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple using a cross tab, also known as conditional aggregation. It would be something like this.

```
select s.ObjectInternalID
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 3 then Value end) as YourDateColumn
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 4 then Value end) as YourFirstSmudgedColumn
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 2 then Value end) as YourColumnThatMightBeAName
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 66 then Value end) as YourSecondSmudgedColumn
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 14 then Value end) as YourSecondDateColumn
from SomeTable s
group by s.ObjectInternalID
```

If you need to add some filtering to this you can easily turn this into a derived table.

```
select *
from
(
    select s.ObjectInternalID
        , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 3 then Value end) as YourDateColumn
        , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 4 then Value end) as YourFirstSmudgedColumn
        , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 2 then Value end) as YourColumnThatMightBeAName
        , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 66 then Value end) as YourSecondSmudgedColumn
        , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 14 then Value end) as YourSecondDateColumn
    from SomeTable s
    group by s.ObjectInternalID
)
where YourColumnThatMightBeAName = 'SomeValueToFind'
```

Keep in mind that since this is an EAV you will have to cast/convert the values when they are a different datatype.

```
Where convert(datetime, YourDateColumn) <= '20160225'
```

If you need to insert into a temp table you should consider converting your string data into a datatype appropriate for the contents. Here is the syntax and how you would convert the two datetime values.

```
select s.ObjectInternalID
    , convert(datetime, MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 3 then Value end)) as YourDateColumn
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 4 then Value end) as YourFirstSmudgedColumn
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 2 then Value end) as YourColumnThatMightBeAName
    , MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 66 then Value end) as YourSecondSmudgedColumn
    , convert(datetime, MAX(Case when UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 14 then Value end)) as YourSecondDateColumn
INTO #SomeTempTable
from SomeTable s
group by s.ObjectInternalID
```

Comment: This created a table that looked good. But how do I now add in a where clause using the new column names? E.g. `where YourDateColumn > '2016-01-01'`. I tried this out, and it says the column doens't exist. Do I have to create a view table first like the answer below suggests?

Comment: I've added the SQL I have now to the question

Comment: @Frantumn I edited my answer with how you can do this.

Comment: I'm going to have to cross reference this data with another table. So I think  I will need to create a temporary table with all of the values, then I can do conditional work on that. I'm still having issues with the temp table based on my SQL above.

Comment: If you only need to reference this once then I would recommend a cte instead of a temp table. It is a little easier on the resources and is easier to code. If you need to reference it in more than 1 query then a temp table is a good solution. I will show the syntax in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view on the table to do the split - it looks as though the field `UserDefinedFieldInternalID` and the content of the field has a strong correlation, at least in terms of datatype - so, assuming you want to extract for a finite set of `UserDefinedFieldInternalID`'s you could construct a view something like:

```
select d2.value, d14.value from thistable d2 join thistable d14 on d2.internalobjectid = d14.internalobjectid
where d2.value = 'his name' and
d2.UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 2 and
d14.UserDefinedFieldInternalID = 14 and
d14.value > "date range"
```

I'd suspect that somewhere else, there's a reference table where you'll find UserDefinedFieldInternalID joining with a list of types, so you might be able to bring that in to tidy things up a bit.

This way of representing data is perfectly valid in applications where the users can in some ways define their own schemas - it doesn't scale all that well, but in small/boutique implementations, that's not a problem (at least not for the first few months/years)

[edit]
To converge a little with the layout of the other answer - here's another way of writing the code above - I've changed the joins to left joins so that if there aren't values matching, it just leaves the resulting value blank.

```
create view user_schema_query_view1 as
select 
s.ObjectInternalID
d3.value as date1,
d4.value as resident1,
d66.value as attending1,
d14.value as date2, 
from
DocUserDefinedData s 
left join DocUserDefinedData d3 on s.ObjectInternalID = d3.ObjectInternalID and 
d3.ObjectInternalID = 3
left join DocUserDefinedData d4 on s.ObjectInternalID = d4.ObjectInternalID and 
d3.ObjectInternalID = 4
left join DocUserDefinedData d66 on s.ObjectInternalID = d66.ObjectInternalID and 
d3.ObjectInternalID = 66
left join DocUserDefinedData d14 on s.ObjectInternalID = d14.ObjectInternalID and 
d3.ObjectInternalID = 14
```

Then, you can query the view using a statement like:

```
select * from user_schema_query_view1
where date1 = "some-date-value" and attending1 = "something else"
```

Try this out first for the structure, and then, if it suits, you could try working on casting the data into more helpful data types.

Comment: Sounds like I needed a combination of what you had and what the other answer had. I'm still stuck while trying to make a temp table though, I've updated my post to show what I have. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd explore this technique, what it does is strip the single table into a series of joined tables, where each join is a filtered set by `UserDefinedFieldInternalID` - once you're happy that you've built it up with all the references you're after, you can wrap it in a `create view myview as select ...` statement - and you can then query this with a statement like: `Select a,b,c from myview where a='something` Once created, there are methods for "materialising" views that will make them faster (essentially making a temp-table out of them) but they are db-specific.